# 2.4 ghz WiFi not working after installing Samsung Evo 960

Tags: network, wifi, ssd

I have MacBook Pro 2014 with latest High Sierra 10.13.5.

Month ago I've replaced my SSD to Samsung Evo 960 with Sintech adapter. When I boot recovery to install Mac OS I tried to connect to my home wifi but it didn't connected. Then I connected to 5 ghz wifi. Mac connected and I forgot about it.

But some days ago I've tried to connect to 2.4 ghz wifi and it didn't connect. I again tried to play at home with 2.4 ghz and found that signal is weak (NetSpot). Mostly it don't connect (write that password is wrong. But if disable password - simply don't connect). It connecting time-to-time, work a bit and then Internet disappears.

I started think about SSD, so I replaced it back to original and all works fine!

So the question is.. What might be wrong? I read something about kapton tape. But first of all I don't understand what to isolate. Secondary I didn't found it in stores. Maybe I can use something another instead of kapton tape?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [2.4GHz is a common frequency used by lots of products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_2.4_GHz_radio_use) and it's not uncommon to get interference from other components (I suspect this is the case).  [Kapton tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapton) is not a common thing - it's typically used in the manufacturing process as a heat insulator; though you can [source it online](https://amzn.to/2Md7qNT).  It's possible it can shield RFI , but without actually putting hands on, I couldn't test to verify.  I would also contact Samsung about this to see their response.

Comment: It's funny but yesterday when swap back to Samsung SSD WiFi still didn't worked. But I just put bottom case over laptop and didn't screw it. But when I mount everything back it started working fine! I can assume that SSD was put somehow wrong or something else. Anyway now all works fine and I am happy :)

Comment: Oh god, today it again stopped connecting to 2.4 wifi :D No idea what happened. I even didn't reboot mac.